# Angular Firebase How to iterate through a list object and take data

Tags: angular, firebase, leaflet, angularfire

I am trying to pull location data from database iterate thorough and display markers on map.
Right now im pulling data with this:

```
this.msgData =this.db.list(`/messages/`).valueChanges();
    this.msgData.take(1).subscribe(msg =>{

console.log(msg);



});
```

output:
[image: output]

As you see location data is stored like that.there is authid-messageid then locationlat and locationlong data.
[image: dbmap]

First idea came to my mind was pull all locationlat locationlong from db somehow store them in an array then using for loop add them to the map but i couldnt really figure out.how to pull locationlat and locationlong of each msg in db ?

thanks

Comment: can you show the result in json

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Vs2jVP9uRdqGUKi9N_IK8Q.png

Comment: Actually also im trying to pull msg and username too for writing on each marker

Comment: Can you be more specific? You say you want to pull lat/lng info and then you show that your request already returns lat/lng info, so what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd5uxg)**

the problem is that we don't know the name of the key of each object in the array so try something like this it works:

```
function getObjectWithoutKnowingKey(data) {
    let objects = [];
    for (var propName in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            objects.push(data[propName]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

in your function :

```
this.msgData =this.db.list(`/messages/`).valueChanges();
    this.msgData.take(1).subscribe(msg =>{

       let data = msg.map(this.getObjectWithoutKnowingKey)

       console.log(data); // [{ locationlat: 1, locationlong: 2, message: 'nsg', username: 'john' }]
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks  now i can reach them with console.log(data[0].locationlat);  but this only pulls 1 first message of each authentication id.what about other messages ? 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/HQPaqFW5SpyKqy0f9399Gw.png

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna say. please edit your question and clarify what you want to mean by  authentication id and put more json .

Comment: @YunusEmreGuneyStudent see the updated I changed the `getObjectWithoutKnowingKey` function